# What is the significance of Jessica drawing a chain of circles?

Tags: analysis, 13-reasons-why

In *13 Reasons Why* S02E03, we see Jessica making an eight shape on her hand:

[image]

Then we see in flashback, she is doing the same but this time on paper:

[image]

I assumed it was the symbol for the digit eight (8) but when we get back to present day it turn out to be a chain of circles:

[image]

But what does it signify? We see them very briefly but I am unable to understand the meaning of it.

Comment: As you said, I think it's a chain to symbolize how Jessica feels trapped and defeated, how she is not able to talk about what happened to her.

Answer (score 1):

A person's subconscious mind is usually dominant when they are doodling such patterns aimlessly. People say that the patterns one's draw helps understand what he/she is [feeling inside](https://www.deviantart.com/liquidblueflame/journal/Psychology-meaning-of-doodles-drawings-220917663).

> Chains can indicate feelings of restriction, particularly in a
>   relationship or in a job. Restrictions can also refer to a person's
>   attitudes and beliefs that don't allow them to do as they wish.
>   Drawing a person in chains can show a feeling of being very stressed.